# how to update input type=" text" with javascript after an operation

Tags: javascript, html

I wish to update the text field with `id=you` after clicking the update button,in the script I have also tried `current=document.getElementById("you");`
`current.innerText=num1;` to no avail,thanks very much for your response.

```
<form name="ADD" >

<input type="text"  name="new1" value="0/><br /><br />

 <input type="text" name="current" id="you" value="" />

 <input type="button" value="update" 

onclick="add(this.form.new1.value,this.form.current.value);" />

</form>

 <script type="text/javascript" >

  var add = function (num1, num2) {

            var current;

            num1 = parseInt(num1);

            num2 = parseInt(num2);

            num2 += num1;

           current= document.getElementById("you");

            current.setAttribute("value", num1);

        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var current = document.getElementById("you"); 
current.value = num1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with basic jQuery:

HTML

```
<form name="ADD" >

<input type="text"  name="new1" value="0/><br /><br />

 <input type="text" name="current" id="you" value="" />

 <input type="button" value="update"/>

</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").clicked(function(){
           $("#you").val("You new value");
     });
});
```

Or in pure jscript:

```
<input type=button value='Update' onclick="add("Your new value");">

<script>
     function add(value){
        var input = document.getElementById("you"); 
        input.value = value;
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Is jQuery even worth mentioning for such a simple task??

Comment: No, but first I miss read the question, and since I already wrote that part of the answer i thought it could stay

Answer (score 0):

try this. it works

```
<form name="ADD">
<input type="text"  name="new1" value="0"/><br /><br />
<input type="text" name="current" id="you" value="" />
<input type="button" value="update"
       onclick="add(this.form.new1.value,this.form.current.value);" />
</form>
<script>
function add(num1, num2) { 
    var current;
    num1 = parseInt(num1);
    num2 = parseInt(num2);
    num2 += num1;
    document.getElementById('you').value = num1;
};
</script>
```